# Store docker machine in D: drive rather than in C:\Users\... windows 7

Tags: windows-7, docker, docker-machine

Is it somehow possible to store docker machine with "virtual machine disk" in D: drive because I don't have enough space on C: drive.
I mean, file `disk` which is now stored in `C:\Users\Gondil\.docker\machine\machines\myvm` Is it possible to store it for example to `D:\vm`? Because when I start some container and it is whole downloaded an it has for example 10GB size, it is quite big for my Sysem SSD.

Is there some config in which I can change directory of created machines?

Comment: Off topic here. Not sure if Docker belongs on Superuser or ServerFault.

Comment: I tried it on SuperUser, nobody answered and when I look to docker site they redirect me to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You could move all .docker and it's sub-directories to the location on your other disk, then mklink to the location on your other disk. For example:

```
mklink /D "C:\Users\Gondil\.docker" "D:\vm\.docker"
```